# Recommendation for PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET in ASMM

Tags: oracle

What can be the value of PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET if we configure the ASMM in oracle 12c ?.Is there any recommendation for this one.Because the sga is only tuned in ASMM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Setting the Initial Value for PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_pga.htm#TGDBA471)

> **To set the initial value for PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET:**
>
> 1. Determine how much of the total physical memory to reserve for the
>      operating system and other non-Oracle applications running on the same
>      system.
>
> For example, you might decide to reserve 20% of the total physical
>   memory for the operating system and other non-Oracle applications,
>   dedicating 80% of the memory on the system to the Oracle database
>   instance.
>
> 2. Divide the remaining available memory between the SGA and the PGA:
>
>    - For OLTP systems, the PGA memory typically makes up a small fraction
>        of the available memory, leaving most of the remaining memory for the
>        SGA.
>
> Oracle recommends initially dedicating 20% of the available memory to
>   the PGA, and 80% to the SGA. Therefore, the initial value of the
>   PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET parameter for an OLTP system can be calculated
>   as:
>
> PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = (total_mem * 0.8) * 0.2 where total_mem is the
>   total amount of physical memory available on the system.
>
> - For DSS systems running large, memory-intensive queries, PGA memory
>     can typically use up to 70% of the available memory.
>
> Oracle recommends initially dedicating 50% of the available memory to
>   the PGA, and 50% to the SGA. Therefore, the initial value of the
>   PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET parameter for a DSS system can be calculated as:
>
> PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = (total_mem * 0.8) * 0.5 where total_mem is the
>   total amount of physical memory available on the system.
>
> For example, if an Oracle database instance is configured to run on a
>   system with 4 GB of physical memory, and if 80% (or 3.2 GB) of the
>   memory is dedicated to the Oracle database instance, then initially
>   set PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET to 640 MB for an OLTP system, or 1,600 MB for
>   a DSS system.

Comment: Is the above recommendation suitable when we change the AMM into ASMM?

Comment: @Visali Yes. *If you are using automatic memory management to manage the database memory on your system, then you do not need to manually tune the PGA as described in this chapter.*